# Wrong _.merge() result

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, merge, lodash

I am trying to merge two object (webpack configs) using lodash.

I have object one:

```js
const obj1 = {
  entry: '/home/ramofx/Projects/app/web/own/react-ts-tasks/frontend/source/index.tsx',
  output: {/**/},
  module: {/**/},
  plugins: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin {/**/},
    HtmlWebpackPlugin {/**/}
  ],
  resolve: {/**/}
}
```

I have object two:

```js
const obj2 = {
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    CleanWebpackPlugin {/**/},
    AggressiveMergingPlugin {/**/}
  ]
}
```

Now I do magic like so:

```js
console.log(
  _.merge(obj1, obj2)
)
```

And this is the result:

```js
{
  entry: '/home/ramofx/Projects/app/web/own/react-ts-tasks/frontend/source/index.tsx',
  output: {/**/},
  module: {/**/},
  plugins: [
    CleanWebpackPlugin {/**/},
    AggressiveMergingPlugin {/**/}
  ],
  resolve: {/**/},
  mode: 'production'
}
```

I am getting 2 plugins instead of 4. Why? I tried `webpack-merge` package and it works perfectly!

Comment: Because how `_.merge()` works with arrays. You can customize using `_.mergeWith()`, but `webpack-merge` was built for webpack configurations, so use it.

Comment: Oh, okay, didn't mention that lodash array merging. Thanks

Comment: The example in the [official documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#merge): `var object = {'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]}; var other = {'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]}; _.merge(object, other); // => {'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }]}` - an array with 2 objects, not 4.